# How can I input negative number without a string error in Python (The input must be in tuples)

Tags: python

```py
def eqQuadratic(Variables):
      valuesoflinear=Variables[1]
      a = float(valuesoflinear[0])
      b = float(valuesoflinear[2])
      c = float(valuesoflinear[4])
      x = float(valuesoflinear[6])

      y = a*x**2 + b*x + c
      return y

input2 = input("input a, x, b, c to calculate the quadratic equation ")
Variables = ("The input for quadratic equation are ", input2)
y = eqQuadratic(Variables)
print("the answer for quadratic equation is ", y)
```

If I input all positive numbers it works, but if I input negative numbers, it won't works.

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/maxime/Desktop/SESAME/PycharmProjects/Neocortex0.0/dj.py", line 14, in 
> y = eqQuadratic(Variables)
> File "C:/Users/maxime/Desktop/SESAME/PycharmProjects/Neocortex0.0/dj.py", line 3, in eqQuadratic
> a = float(valuesoflinear[0])
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

How can I have the 4 different values from the `input()`command and convert them into float number.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample input from the user and an output from your program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you get when you run that code.

Comment: Probably because you are basing the code on the numbers location in a string, adding `-` changes this location. Split the numbers to a list instead. This also won't work if you enter 2 digits number.

Comment: `input2` (and hence `Variables[1]` is a string.  You are taking the 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th character of that string and trying to convert them to floats.  I ASSUME you meant to use `input2.split()`.  Why are you passing that other string to the function?  It doesn't need your explanation.

Comment: And what is the purpose of `Variables = ("The input for quadratic equation are ", input2)`?

Comment: And, by the way, you said "it works".  It absolutely does not work.  Did you manually check any of the equations you entered?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you don't ask for 4 number. so the `valuesoflinear[0]` is just a sign `-`. You need to ask 4 number that can be negartive like `-1`

here a solution :

```
def eqQuadratic(Variables):
    a = float(Variables[0])
    b = float(Variables[1])
    c = float(Variables[2])
    x = float(Variables[3])

    y = a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
    return y


inputa = input("input a to calculate the quadratic equation ")
inputx = input("input x to calculate the quadratic equation ")
inputb = input("input b to calculate the quadratic equation ")
inputc = input("input c to calculate the quadratic equation ")
# Variables = ("The input for quadratic equation are ", input2)
y = eqQuadratic([inputa,inputx,inputb,inputc])
print("the answer for quadratic equation is ", y)
```

You can ask for several input in a row but you have to be careful if less or more than 4 parameters are enter

```
def eqQuadratic(Variables):
    a = float(Variables[0])
    b = float(Variables[1])
    c = float(Variables[2])
    x = float(Variables[3])

    y = a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
    return y


input2 = input("input a, x, b, c to calculate the quadratic equation ").split()
# Variables = ("The input for quadratic equation are ", input2)
if not len(input2) == 4:
    print('you need to enter 4 param')
else:
    y = eqQuadratic(input2)
    print("the answer for quadratic equation is ", y)
```

Comment: I think I understood the problem. What the questioner does is input some values seperated by a comma, like "1,3,5,4". That's why accessing the indices 0, 2, 4 and 6 works for positive values. So this isn't really the answer, you should edit it so that it uses an input string, removes all spaces and splits it by commas, casting the values of the result array to floats.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I meant sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: if you separate numbers with comma, you have to consider them into the split like `.replace(',',' ').replace('/',' ')split()`. or use the re module.

Comment: I think the best is to ask specifically for each number. this would avoid misinput from the user.

Comment: @ymmx yes I know it's better to input each number,but for this assignment it requires me to do the input in Tuples method.