# I can't input negative numbers in my quadratic equation calculator problem in Python (Tuples)

Tags: python

```py
def eqQuadratic(Variables):
    valuesoflinear=Variables[1]
    a = float(valuesoflinear[0])
    b = float(valuesoflinear[2])
    c = float(valuesoflinear[4])
    x = float(valuesoflinear[6])
    
    
    
    y = a*x**2 + b*x + c
    return y

input2 = input("input a, x, b, c to calculate the quadratic equation ")
y = eqQuadratic(Variables)
print("the answer for quadratic equation is ", y)
```

So in this quadratic equation calculator code, If I input all positive numbers it will work. But If I input negative numbers, it will give me an error. Please note that the input is must in Tuples format.  Need your help! Thx

Comment: Please update your question with a sample input from the user and an output from your program. If you are receiving an error, then also add the full error traceback.

Comment: Please also properly format your code

Comment: Please also respond quickly because I am ready to close this as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72196587)